# Transforming an output list with multiple columns into a table in R

Tags: r, list, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I've an output table from R which is of type `"list"`:

```
> print(confMat)
Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)

          Reference
Prediction Feeding Foraging Standing
  Feeding       44        0        2
  Foraging       0       32        0
  Standing       0        0       22

 Accuracy (average) : 0.98

> typeof(confMat)
[1] "list"
```

I would like to transform it into a table with headers as such:

```
             Feeding Foraging Standing
  Feeding       44        0        2
  Foraging       0       32        0
  Standing       0        0       22
```

So that I can extract the values in the table as follows:

```
x<-confMat[1:1]
print(x)
44
```

I've tried using:

```
confMat <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(confMat), nrow=length(confMat), byrow=T))
```

However, I dont get the desired output I would like to:

```
> dput(confMat)
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("0", 
"2", "44", "overall"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "30", "32"), class = "factor"), 
    X3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "22", "Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) Confusion Matrix"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I'm sorry if this question is too basic. I'm new to R so I hope somebody can help me! Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract it as shown below:

```
 library(caret)
train_set<-createDataPartition(iris$Species,p=0.8,list=FALSE)
valid_set<-iris[-train_set,]
train_set<-iris[train_set,]
ctrl<-trainControl(method="cv",number=5)
set.seed(233)
mk<-train(Species~.,data=train_set,method="knn",trControl = ctrl,metric="Accuracy")
```

**Target**

```
  confusionMatrix(mk)["table"][[1]]
            Reference
Prediction       setosa versicolor  virginica
  setosa     33.3333333  0.0000000  0.0000000
  versicolor  0.0000000 32.5000000  2.5000000
  virginica   0.0000000  0.8333333 30.8333333
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm still getting a list: ```> confMat<-confusionMatrix(knnFit)["table"]
> print(confMat)
$table
          Reference
Prediction Feeding Foraging Standing
  Feeding       44        0        2
  Foraging       0       32        0
  Standing       0        0       22

> typeof(confMat)
[1] "list"```

Comment: @juancda4 check the update and it produces a `table` not `data.frame`. A `data.frame` is not appropriate for a confusion matrix(in my opinion). You should also consider accepting answers that help you solve your problem by clicking the tick. Do so for the past questions too.